# Quotes inside Quotes inside another Quotes

Tags: php, html

```
<input <?php echo $credit['credit_1']=='0'?'placeholder="Credit 1"':'value="$credit['credit_1']"';?> >
```

My question is, which one is correct and why?

```
1. 'value="$credit_exm['credit_1']"'

2. 'value="$credit_exm["credit_1"]"'
```

Comment: Concatenate those strings and problem solved

Comment: Or use braces... or sprintf.

Comment: either that or use http://php.net/sprintf

Comment: As long as nested quotes are of a different type your OK.  You can escape quotes so `"\""` is OK.

Comment: like? @Nigel Ren

Comment: Your first example uses single quotes inside double quotes, so this is OK, but in your second example, as your string is in double quotes - it effectively gets ended by the first quote in `"credit_1"`.  One big thing to be careful of is that single quotes and double quoted strings have very different rules.

Comment: Thank you all.
I've solved, "concatenation worked well!"

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="credit_8" <?php echo $credit_exm['credit_8']=='0'?'placeholder="Credit 8"':'value="'.$credit_exm['credit_8'].'"';
          ?>
         >`

Answer (score 1):

Answer: neither.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and
>   escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they
>   occur in single quoted strings.

Here are different approaches to arrive at the same output:

```
<?php
$my['planet'] = 'Earth!';
$strings = [];
array_push(
    $strings,
    'Hello "' . $my['planet'] . '"',
    "Hello \"${my['planet']}\"",
    "Hello \"{$my['planet']}\"",
    "Hello \"$my[planet]\"",
    sprintf('Hello "%s"', $my['planet'])
);

var_export($strings);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'Hello "Earth!"',
    1 => 'Hello "Earth!"',
    2 => 'Hello "Earth!"',
    3 => 'Hello "Earth!"',
    4 => 'Hello "Earth!"',
)
```

Personally I find I can easily get into a muddle when doing this, so often opt for the sprintf approach.

Comment: The ambiguous/surprise case is `"Hello \"$my[planet]\""`, where the key isn't quoted. It looks here as if I'm using an undefined constant as a key and you may expect Php to raise a notice which it doesn't.  This must be a 'feature'.

Comment: Do read all the documentation / man page for strings as linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error.

Must:

```
<input <?php echo $credit['credit_1'] == '0' ? 'placeholder="Credit 1"' : 'value="' . $credit["credit_1"] . '"'; ?> >
```